# Adding an onclick event using addEventListener says uncaught type error undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this specific object that I am creating i.e., where I have methods that I am trying to attach event listeners to a method but it keeps showing:

> "uncaught type error undefined is not a function"

in this case when I try to `addEventListener`with a function.

Am I doing something wrong here? I am new to JS development.

```
var a = function() {

    handleClick = function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
            i.addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);
        }
    }

    numberClick = function(e) {
        alert("this is a button");
    }

}();
```

Comment: `i` is a number; `inputs[i]` is the element you want.

Comment: Also, without `var` you are automatically pushing those functions into the global scope.

Comment: yeah, i have used var in my code.. thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 0):

You should do `inputs[i].addEventListener`. `i` is the index of the array-like object of `input`s. So the first `i` would be `0`, but `inputs[i]` would be the `input` element you are expecting.

```
var a = function (){
    var handleClick = function(){
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
        for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
            inputs[i].addEventListener("click", numberClick, false);
        }
    };

    var numberClick = function(e){
        alert("this is a button");
    };
}();
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that typo.